# Can an astrologer himself cast the Prasna Kundali for one of his own questions?

Tags: astrology, horary-astrology

[Horary astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horary_astrology) is different from natal astrology . In the later, we need to have the birth details of the native, or the natal chart, which is not needed in Horary.

In Horary, a person A goes to another person B (who is of course the astrologer) with a question in mind.

And, based on the time and place, when and where, the question has being asked, the astrologer casts a chart. (This is called the Prashna Kundali).

He, then analyzes the chart, according to the methods of the doctrines, in order to give an answer to person A's question.

Now, suppose the person A himself is an adept in Horary. Can he himself cast the Prashna Kundali as per the time when the question arose in his mind? Or  this is not allowed at all as per the doctrines of Horary? Or in other words, is the involvement of the two persons a must here?

Comment: yes ghe can....

Comment: You can add an answer. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: But if something is not forbidden then how can i bring references for not being forbidden

Comment: Then how do u know that it is not forbidden? You must have read that in some books. Those books can be cited. Anyways, attempt an answer from whatever u know about this. @RakeshJoshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person, whoever may be, if s/he can understand and predict something in horary (question), can herself/himself cast the Prashna Kundali as per the time when the question had arisen in their mind.

**`Or this is not allowed at all as per the doctrines of Horary?`**

why not, 100% allowed.

**`in other words, is the involvement of the two persons a must here?`**

Not at all required. If one is having sufficient skills in astrology, then, s/he alone can cast a prasna kundli and predict and check the results.

Astrology is a science !!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but can u add some authentic sources in support of the assertions u make?

Comment: Welcome. I can not add any. But I am already an astrologer, practicing horary. I shall surely give some horary examples here, which I have prepared and studied myself. Please wait 3 to 4 days, so that i can paste the example in a proper way in this thread.

Comment: its ok, no problem.

Comment: You can cite any books on the subject that will do..